# ¿Como convertir un String para ejecutar una consulta con clausula IN en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla Lotes el cual tiene un campo CalidadId de tipo entero.
Tengo otra tabla Calidades con un campo IdCalidad de tipo entero

Necesitó hacer esto:

```
SELECT * FROM Format WHERE CalidadId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

pero obteniendo los valores que van dentro del IN de la forma que describo en este código
todo va bien porque obtengo una cadena de esta forma '1,2,3,4,5,6', pero al ejecutar me devuelve :

```
Error de conversión al convertir el valor varchar '1,2,3,4,5,6' al tipo de datos int.
```

"No me pidan que ejecute un JOIN porque en realidad el ejercicio es muy largo y solo resumo lo que en realidad necesitó para resolver"

```
DECLARE @TablaCalidades Table (IdCalidad Int Identity(1,1), ValorIdCalidad varchar(10));
 INSERT INTO @TablaCalidades  SELECT CalidadId FROM Calidades;
 --SELECT * FROM @TablaCalidades
 DECLARE @strCalidades VARCHAR(300);
 DECLARE @nRows INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TablaCalidades);
 DECLARE @index INT = 1;
 WHILE(@index <= @nrows)
   BEGIN 
   IF(@index = 1)
     BEGIN
       SET @strCalidades = (SELECT ValorIdCalidad FROM @TablaCalidades WHERE IdCalidad = @index);
     END
     ELSE 
     BEGIN
         SET @strCalidades = CONCAT(@strCalidades , ',' , (SELECT ValorIdCalidad FROM @TablaCalidades WHERE IdCalidad = @index));
     END
   SET @index = @index + 1;
   END


SELECT  * FROM Lotes   WHERE dtEliminado IS NULL AND CalidadFK IN (@strCalidades)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, un `IN` espera básicamente un conjunto de valores o lista, lo que le estas pasando es una cadena y efectivamente como ya te contestaron, tienes que desarmar esta cadena y convertirla en un conjunto de filas. Este es un tema tratado hasta el cansancio en el sitio, hay varias formas de resolverlo (usa el buscador), si tu versión del motor lo permiten `STRING_SPLIT()` es una buena alternativa.

Ahora bien, lo que estás queriendo hacer no tiene sentido, tienes ya los valores de `CalidadFK` en la tabla `Calidades`, ¿para que quieres armar lo que va dentro del `IN`? me da la impresión que tal vez no sepas que puedes hacer simplemente esto:

```
 SELECT * 
        FROM Lotes 
        WHERE dtEliminado IS NULL 
              AND CalidadFK IN (SELECT CalidadId FROM Calidades)
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre usar `STRING_SPLIT`, el problema es que te va a retornar una lista de string, por lo que habría que hacer un `CAST`

```
SELECT * FROM Lotes WHERE dtEliminado IS NULL AND CalidadFK IN (select cast(value as integer) from STRING_SPLIT(@strCalidades,','))
```